# XMLHttpRequest fails with error code 415: Cannot process the message

Tags: javascript, soap, dynamics-crm-2015

Im working in a CRM 2015 Online enivronment. I'm trying to trigger a CRM workflow from an HTML Webressource. The HTML Webressource is opened by a JavaScript Webressource.

My Problem: After running the following code, I am getting this error message:
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 (Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'.)**

This is my code:

```
function runWorkflow()
{
    var entityId = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"; //Guid of record that workflow is to run on.
    var workflowId = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"; //Workflow Guid.
    var url = window.parent.Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();

    var OrgServicePath = "/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc";
    url = url + OrgServicePath;
    var request;
    request = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
    "<s:Body>" +
    "<Execute xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">" +
      "<request i:type=\"b:ExecuteWorkflowRequest\" xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts\" xmlns:b=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2011/Contracts\">" +
        "<a:Parameters xmlns:c=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic\">" +
          "<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>" +
            "<c:key>EntityId</c:key>" +
            "<c:value i:type=\"d:guid\" xmlns:d=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">" + entityId + "</c:value>" +
          "</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>" +
          "<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>" +
            "<c:key>WorkflowId</c:key>" +
            "<c:value i:type=\"d:guid\" xmlns:d=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">" + workflowId + "</c:value>" +
          "</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>" +
        "</a:Parameters>" +
        "<a:RequestId i:nil=\"true\" />" +
        "<a:RequestName>ExecuteWorkflow</a:RequestName>" +
      "</request>" +
    "</Execute>" +
    "</s:Body>" +
    "</s:Envelope>";

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", url, true)
    // Responses will return XML. It isn't possible to return JSON.
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml, text/xml, */*");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    req.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/Execute");
    req.onreadystatechange = function () { assignResponse(req); };
    req.send(request);
}
```

After I did some research, I found the following text:

> this is usually a mismatch in the client/server bindings, where the
>   message version in the service uses SOAP 1.2 (which expects
>   application/soap+xml) and the version in the client uses SOAP 1.1
>   (which sends text/xml). WSHttpBinding uses SOAP 1.2, BasicHttpBinding
>   uses SOAP 1.1.

So I'm not quite sure how I can fix my problem. Anyone got a solution?

Answer (score 0):

While it appears that you [copy/pasted](http://crminpractice.blogspot.com/2012/04/executing-crm-2011-workflow-via.html) your code from the internet, you also made some slight changes to it: You removed the /web from the end of the Organization.svc URL. It is important to understand that there is a difference between the two.

MSDN explains the difference in [Use the Modern app SOAP endpoint for modern applications with web resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg490657.aspx):

> Unlike the REST endpoint for web resources, the SOAP endpoint uses the
>   Organization service. This is the same service used when writing
>   applications that exist outside of the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015
>   application. The differences are:
>
> - Requests are sent to a different
>     URL: /XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web.